# Python: Returning a substring of a str column (type = str) is failing with "expected str or bytes-like object" despite being converted

Tags: python, regex, string

I have some code that returns to a column a response from the Google Maps API. I want to only select the latitude and longitude from the location key in the below, and put the floats into separate columns (see the bold text):

```
[{'address_components': 
[{'long_name': 'Winneba', 'short_name': 'Winneba', 'types': ['locality', 
'political']}, {'long_name': 'Awutu', 'short_name': 'Awutu', 'types': 
['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Central', 
'short_name': 'Central', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 
'political']}, {'long_name': 'Ghana', 'short_name': 'GH', 'types': 
['country', 'political']}], 'formatted_address': 'Winneba, Ghana', 
'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 5.404194800000001, 'lng': 
-0.6021021999999999}, 'southwest': {'lat': 5.3282471, 'lng': 
-0.6561327000000001}}, 

**'location': {'lat': 5.3622295, 'lng': -0.6298922}**, 

'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 
 5.404194800000001, 'lng': -0.6021021999999999}, 'southwest': {'lat': 
 5.3282471, 'lng': -0.6561327000000001}}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJG-Pj_-
 g03g8RyVpI4vxYGko', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}]
```

I've tried a few different methods, including to_json, but that causes strange behaviour where the json is applied to every row in the dataframe. So every row has the json for all of the cities in my dataset

Here is the dataframe, data:

[image]

So I want to extract just the location element from the last column, then have one column for latitude and another for longitude

I have the below code, and both ways of converting to str do not work:

```
data['geocode_result'] = data['geocode_result'].astype('str')
# data['geocode_result'] = data['geocode_result'].astype('|S')
string= data['geocode_result']
re.search(r'\'location\'\: \{\'lat\'\: (\d*.\d*)', string).group(1)
```

It throws the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ca085f711fda> in <module>()
  2 # data['geocode_result'] = data['geocode_result'].astype('|S')
  3 string= data['geocode_result']
----> 4 re.search(r'\'location\'\: \{\'lat\'\: (\d*.\d*)', string).group(1)

C:\Users\[ I deleted this] in search(pattern, string, flags)
180     """Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
181     a match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 182     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
183 
184 def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Many thanks

---

Full code below:

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='API KEY')
download_path = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\'
data = pd.read_csv(download_path+'Ghana cities test.csv')
# The above is the spreadsheet containing city names that I want to 
look up using the Google Maps API

city = data['city']
country = data['country']
ghana_city = city + ', ' + country
# The above combines city and country to allow for better searching

data['ghana_city'] = ghana_city
data['ghana_city'] = data['ghana_city'].astype('str')

data['geocode_result'] = data['ghana_city'].map(gmaps.geocode)
# Above searches Google API for every single||country combination and 
returns the Google search results - from this I want the location
```

Comment: What you're doing wrong is using regex to parse JSON. Why would you do that? In fact why are you converting to a string in the first place?

Comment: I'm converting to a string because when using to_json to isolate the key I need, location, it seeing this strange result where the JSON response for every city is placed in the value for every row in my dataset. For example, New York would have Chicago, San Fran, London data in etc

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json. `import json` it's part of the standard library.

Comment: I was importing json, despite being unable to replicate my previous error, i'm now getting the error "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" - I'm guessing that the response is too many levels deep to handle correctly

Comment: You're going to need to show more code. How are you getting this data in the first place, how are you importing it into the dataframe, and how are you outputting it?

Comment: Sure, i've updated the answer - thanks

Comment: I tried another approach, which is to try splitting the column's data using: "string = data['geocode_result']
stringstring = string.astype('str')
stringafterword = re.split('location',stringstring)[-1]"

Comment: But I get the same damn error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
"